# Edit VSCode's settings with JSON?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to like editing VSCode's settings in the old way..using JSON.

Is it possible to forgo the Settings UI, and edit the settings JSON directly?

Answer (score 4):

Visual Student Code has three ways to edit the `settings.json` file - depending on how you want it to act:

1. In Workspace
2. In Folder
3. Globally

**Global** 
Navigate to the `settings.json` file: `File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json"`

**For settings within a project folder:**

1. Create a new directory named `.vscode` in the root of your project
2. Create a `settings.json` file and add your settings there

**Workspace**

After you save a workspace, the file `workSpace.code-workspace` gets generated. Then add a settings key to the file with all your settings you want defined for the workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command menu (ctrl+shift+p) and type `open settings`. You'll see several options for different levels of settings.

Since you like the JSON method of using the settings, there is a setting in the new UI to change the default settings editor: `workbench.settings.editor`