# VS Code: You have deprecated linting or formatting settings for Python

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I open VSCode and open a remote session to our dev server over SSH I'm greeted with this message:

[image: You have deprecated linting or formatting settings for Python.]

In the logs I see these errors:

```
[error] Following setting is deprecated: "python.linting.flake8Enabled"
[error] All settings starting with "python.linting." are deprecated and can be removed from settings.
[error] Linting features have been moved to separate linter extensions.
[error] See here for more information: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting
```

I tried to disable and re-enable Flake8 but that didn't help. How do I remove the linting stuff from settings as it recommends? It's not a biggie but it is a little annoying.

Comment: Open user settings json. Invalid settings will be grayed out. Delete the ones you don't want. Restart vscode.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out this linting config was on my Mac, not on the remote server. Sorted now.

Comment: I've the same issue, but there is no entry at all that corresponds to the deprecated lines nor that is grayed out in my user or system JSON setting file. Where else can be the culprit line?

Comment: @AndreaMoro I deleted my workspace settings file (e.g. PROJECT/.vscode/settings.json) in addition to changing the global settings. Then the warning was gone. If you want to keep some workspace settings, only remove the deprecated lines instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: The 'grayed out' settings is a red-herring.  My "python.linting.flake8Enabled: True" line looked normal.  Also, since I use flake8, it was apparently benign on quick inspection.  However, whatever the case, if you use the flake8 extension, kill this line to regain your sanity.

Answer (score 26):

**Issue**: Deprecated settings in VSCode.

**Fix**:

1. Open VSCode user settings JSON ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)).
2. Delete the grayed out (deprecated) settings.
3. Save and restart VSCode.

**Note**: This may be a workspace setting, meaning that you'll find the relevant settings.json within your current project's `.vscode` folder.

Either way, you should be able to open and review them both by using the command palette in VS Code.

Comment: "Open VSCode user settings JSON." -> how / where to find that?

Comment: @I-P-X Like anything in VSCode: Ctrl+Shift+P, then write something like ">user settin" and it will find the entry you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61435631/4722345

Comment: For me in addition to removing the greyed out lines I also needed to remove the section where `editor.defaultFormatter` was set to `ms-python`.

Comment: Thank you! This has been annoying me for a few weeks now. Turned out it was not in the remote settings where I looked before, but in the local ones.

Comment: For context, VS Code made this change in Sep 2023: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Migration-to-Python-Tools-Extensions

Answer (score 8):

Just in case somebody else stumble across this. I was having the same annoying error message, but no grayed out lines in neither the user os system setting.

A `find . -type f -name "*.*" -exec grep "python.linting" {} +` outlined the presence of another general setting files in `./.vscode/settings.json` that apparently was not picked by the VS code. Upon deleting the incriminated lines  the error message disappeared.

I'm on an Ubuntu machine, but if I'm not mistaken the same path is used in a Mac environment.

Comment: Facing similar issue on Windows 11, any idea how to look at? I can't see the greyed out lint line in settings.json

Comment: It's almost 17 years I'm not using Windows on a regular basis, so can't tell where the user folder is now, but I would look into anything hidden inside your user profile folder. There will be something VScode named. Something like `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`??

Comment: Turns out it had nothing to do with python.linting in `settings.json`. I simply had to install autopep8 for python from extensions and change `@id:editor.defaultFormatter @lang:python editor.defaultFormatter` in settings to `autopep8` from `ms-python.python`

Comment: This worked in macOS. For me, the hidden settings file was "~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json".

Comment: The location of the `settings.json` depends on platform and in case of running VS Code on (Windows) WSL, the Windows-side settings are taken into account too. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_changing-settingsjson

**Settings file locations**

Depending on your platform, the user settings file is located here:

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Answer (score 4):

For Windows users who are still facing this issue and can't find `python.linting` line in `settings.json` in VSCode files. Here is what worked for me.

1. Install autopep8 extension from the extensions store in VSCode.
2. Go to settings in vs code.
3. Type `@id:editor.defaultFormatter @lang:python editor.defaultFormatter` in search settings and change it to `autopep8` from `ms-python.python`

This should solve the issue